# WCF calls fail in unit tests on build server

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild

We are running an updated 2008 server with TFS 2012 and VS 2012 running on the development machines. The solution uses MSBuild to deploy and run tests on the server. All of the tests pass on the development boxes but only the tests that do not call locally deployed WCF servers (hosted in IIS) fail. The exception for all service calls are as follows:

```
>     Test method TestProject.TestClass.TestMethod threw exception: 
>     System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
> cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
>      
>     Server stack trace: 
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
> timeout)
>        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
>     Exception rethrown at [0
enter code here
```

NETWORK SERVICE has the appropriate permissions. The power is on. Any thoughts?

Comment: technically if you are calling a web service, I'd argue these aren't unit tests but that's beside the point.  Have you looked into WCF Tracing?  Turn on the WCF Tracing capabilities in the config files to see if you get anything.  Also, what URL are you using to hit WCF?  localhost?  Maybe it's a loopback thing or a DNS resolution thing, etc.

Comment: Agreed, these are not really unit tests. 

So I have made a little more progress: this seems to be a permissions issue as MSTest runs locally under my account but on the build server it runs as NETWORK SERVICE. The WCF trace shows a SecurityNegotiationException. I guess my question now is.... _what permission am I missing?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. First a little background on the **set up**:

The service in question is configured with user name authentication leveraging a SQL membership provider and  a service certificate. Authorization is done using ASP.NET role provider. The binding being used is a NetTcpBinding with message security on and configured to user name.

**The problem** turned out to be as follows: MSBuild and MSTest on my local box ran under my account. Here the cert I generated locally that was used for authorizat was added to the Current User \ Trusted People which is fine; but on the build box since MSBuild and MSTest run under NETWORK SERVICE, WCF refused the handshake. **The solution** to this problem was to add the test cert to the Local Computer \ Trusted People store.